what generates the spikes in the curve produced from MATLAB B-spline code?
I have come across a MATALB code for B-spline smoothing function. In the produced curve there are some spikes which are not logical. The original MATLAB code can be found in 2D B-Spline approximation in Matlab.
The generated curve using the user defined MATALB function is shown in the figure Curve Produced by the user defined function:

While the curve produced using the built-in MATALB function (as shown in the code below) is shown in the figure Curve Produced by the MATLAB built-in function:
:
close all; clearvars; clc

c = [0.0 1.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0;  % x components
    0.0 1.0 1.0 0.5 0.5 0.0]; % y components
cpts = c;

tpts = [0 max(cpts,[],'all')];

tvec = 0:0.001:max(cpts,[],'all');

[q, qd, qdd, pp] = bsplinepolytraj(cpts,tpts,tvec);

figure
hold all
plot(cpts(1,:),cpts(2,:),'xb-')
plot(q(1,:), q(2,:))
grid on;
grid minor;
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
ylim([min(cpts(2,:)) max(cpts(2,:))*1.25]);
hold off 

As we can see in the user defined function there are some spikes in the curve produced while it supposedly to be nice and smooth as the one produced by the built-in MATALB function " bsplinepolytraj ". Can anyone figure out where are the errors that cause the spikes in the curve?

Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], some reference to someone else's code and your results being "weird" is not a specific enough problem statement for us to do anything about

@Wolfie I have edited the question as much as I understand from your comment.

Please, display both functions on one figure, so difference can be clearly seen.

@DmitryMesserman I think the difference is clear enough, they are the big spikes which appear to point normal to the curves in two spots on the yellow line

Not an answer, but a comment; the errors are happening at precisely the 1001th and 2001th elements in the array, so I expect the number of spikes to equal your spline order minus $1$. I suspect it has to do with the interaction of the two submodules in the code, BaseSpline and KnotVector, not updating the value of the curve correctly due to exiting some loop procedure one element too early.

The original question now has an answer. Your question seems like a duplicate to me. I mean, basically, you are asking about the solution to the original question, right? Or have I missed something?

@aghostinthefigures you are right about the location  where the spikes generated. But I still cannot figure it out which part of the code  cause such spikes.
